# Archive files with certain extension

Tags: windows, scripting, automation

So I need a Windows Script that I can tell it a directory to go through and it will parse all sub-directories and while in each subdir, will archive all files with a certain file extension and keep it in the same subdir, then move onto the next one.

What's the best way to go about this? Perl Automation Scripting, AutoIt?

Any sample code you guys can give me?

Comment: What do you mean by "archive", exactly? Some archiving tools will do this in a single command...

Comment: For example, I have a directory with say 15 subdirectories, in turn which have each have more subdirectories. There are certain file extensions Sharepoint doesn't like, and therefore all these have to be zipped up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below one way I would do it in AutoIt since you asked. Replace the MsgBox line with whatever code you need to do whatever it is your wanting to do. AutoIt is fun stuff!

```
#include <File.au3>

archiveDir(InputBox("Path","Enter your start path."))

Func archiveDir($rootDirectory)
    $aFiles = _FileListToArray($rootDirectory)

    For $i = 1 To UBound($aFiles) - 1
        If StringInStr(FileGetAttrib($aFiles[$i]),"D") Then archiveDir($rootDirectory & $aFiles[$i] & "\")
        MsgBox(0,"This would be your archive step!",'"Archiving" ' & $rootDirectory & $aFiles[$i])
    Next
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 3):

Perl is more powerful than batch scripts but since Perl is not included with windows it seems overkill for tasks such as this one. This should for example work:

```
FOR /R C:\hello\ %%G IN (*.txt) DO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %%G.zip %%G && del %%G
```

Note that you cannot do this directly in the prompt, you must save it as a .bat file. It is of course also possible to allow the user to specify the paths and extensions with command line like this:

```
FOR /R %1 %%G IN (%2) DO "c:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a %%G.zip %%G && del %%G
```

More information about FOR and other windows command line commands can be found here: http://ss64.com/nt/

This would then be run with:

```
test.bat C:\Hello\ *.txt
```

EDIT: This obviously requires you to have 7-Zip installed but it's pretty obvious where to change the code if you want to use some other zipper. Also keep in mind to always be Extremely careful when experimenting with scripts such as this. One small mistake could have it delete a lot of files, so you should always test it on a copy of the file system until you are absolutely sure it works.

Comment: So, say I create a .bat file, content of the second one to specify the file extensions. How would I run that?

Comment: You would run it with "test.bat c:\hello\ txt". Alternatively you could replace the *.%2 in the batfile with simply %2 to let you specify any wildcards.
@mobrule: Let me rephrase: It does run natively, but only if you install a Perl interpreter like ActivePerl on your system. It is useful for many purposes, but it seems like overkill here.

Comment: Note - you can use the commandline version of 7-zip to avoid the need to install anything.  The commandline version executable is called 7za.exe.

Answer (score 3):

FORFILES is included with Windows and may be more applicable than FOR to what you're trying to do:

> FORFILES [/P pathname] [/M searchmask]
>   [/S]
>            [/C command] [/D [+ | -] {MM/dd/yyyy | dd}]
>
> Description:
>       Selects a file (or set of files) and executes a
>       command on that file. This is helpful for batch jobs.
>
> Parameter List:
>
> ```
> /P    pathname      Indicates the path to start searching.
>                     The default folder is the current working
>                     directory (.).
>
> /M    searchmask    Searches files according to a searchmask.
>                     The default searchmask is '*' .
>
> /S                  Instructs forfiles to recurse into
>                     subdirectories. Like "DIR /S".
>
> /C    command       Indicates the command to execute for each file.
>                     Command strings should be wrapped in double
>                     quotes.
>
>                     The default command is "cmd /c echo @file".
>
>                     The following variables can be used in the
>                     command string:
>                     @file    - returns the name of the file.
>                     @fname   - returns the file name without
>                                extension.
>                     @ext     - returns only the extension of the
>                                file.
>                     @path    - returns the full path of the file.
>                     @relpath - returns the relative path of the
>                                file.
>                     @isdir   - returns "TRUE" if a file type is
>                                a directory, and "FALSE" for files.
>                     @fsize   - returns the size of the file in
>                                bytes.
>                     @fdate   - returns the last modified date of the
>                                file.
>                     @ftime   - returns the last modified time of the
>                                file.
>
>                     To include special characters in the command
>                     line, use the hexadecimal code for the character
>                     in 0xHH format (ex. 0x09 for tab). Internal
>                     CMD.exe commands should be preceded with
>                     "cmd /c".
>
> /D    date          Selects files with a last modified date greater
>                     than or equal to (+), or less than or equal to
>                     (-), the specified date using the
>                     "MM/dd/yyyy" format; or selects files with a
>                     last modified date greater than or equal to (+)
>                     the current date plus "dd" days, or less than or
>                     equal to (-) the current date minus "dd" days. A
>                     valid "dd" number of days can be any number in
>                     the range of 0 - 32768.
>                     "+" is taken as default sign if not specified.
> ```

Comment: Not "included with Windows". It is part of the Windows Resource Kit.

Comment: Beginning with Windows Vista, FORFILES is included natively with Windows, no Resource Kit necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be:

```
my $dirCnt = 0;
traverse_directory('C:\Test');

sub traverse_directory{
    my $directory = shift(@_);  
    $dirCnt++;

    my $dirHandle = "DIR".$dirCnt;    
    opendir($dirHandle, $directory);

    while (defined(my $file = readdir($dirHandle))){
         next if $file =~ /^\.\.?$/;                # skip . and .. ...
         if (-d "$directory\\$file"){  traverse_directory("$directory\\$file");  }
         if ($file =~ /\.txt/){  #find txt files, for example

             print "$file\n";      #do something with the text file here
         }
    }
    closedir($dirHandle);
}
```